# Sound recording with FMOD library

Tags: c++, recording, fmod

Is there a C++ tutorial on FMOD that shows how to record sound from microphone?
Is it even possible?!
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed possible. Check FMOD example directory(\FMOD SoundSystem\FMOD Programmers API Win32\examples\recording) and you will find **"recording"** example.

> /*===============================================================================================
>   Record example  Copyright (c), Firelight Technologies Pty, Ltd
>   2004-2010.
>
> This example shows how to record a sound, then write it to a wav
>   file.  It then shows how to play a sound while it is being recorded
>   to.  Because it is recording, the  sound playback has to be delayed a
>   little bit so that the playback doesn't play part of the  buffer that
>   is still being written to.
>   ===============================================================================================*/