# Recording sound in real time with c++ or C#

Tags: c#, c++, audio, real-time, signal-processing

I have a professional sound card, and I want to record the signals from the guitar with c++ or c# for developing guitar effects in real time.

How can i record in real time through a c++ method ?

Is it mean that I need the sound card API ? 
[this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316764%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although may not be as easy as using a pre-built library, you may be able to get a C++ SDK for your sound card from the manufacturer. I would start by browsing their site or contacting support.

If that isn't an option, you can also use DirectSound which is part of the DirectX family of products. The learning curve is fairly steep but I believe it should do just about anything you want.

One final option is to look at a favorite tool (such as sound forge). A number of these tools support automation which means you can click through the app, decide what you want, then automate that sequence of events ([See this](http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/download/devkits) as an example).

Hope that helps, best of luck!

*Side Note:* I have developed a number of hardware interfaces and in my experience its best to start with an example that does at least something like what you are looking for, then modify the code from there. If any particular option doesn't have an example like this I would probably skip it in favor of an example that does.

**Examples**

*Direct Sound* - Microsoft has a learning site for direct sound which you can [find here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416964%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I also found [this blog article](http://khason.net/blog/capturing-and-streaming-sound-by-using-directsound-with-c/) which has an example for recording audio with direct sound.

*Sound Forge* - If you download the "Script Developers Kit" there are examples for C# in the scripts folder that should get you started. I believe this particular tool is more focused on editing and effects but I am guessing there should be automation for recording.

Comment: thanks a lot :) +1 for your answer. 
do you have any simple example? I know that the sampling is PCM.. I think I would start from capturing the sound from the laptop's integrated sound card line-in input, for basic example.. and then trying to ask the manufacture if there is an SDK for my professional sound card.. can you provide an example for this ? It would be helpful :)

Comment: @Elior Added some links to my post. I would start with those and see where they take you!

Comment: all sound card are using the asio4all, no? so where can I find the sdk for this?

Comment: As of my writing this comment you can find the OEM SDK on this site: http://mtippach.proboards.com/thread/1761   The main difference between ASIO and DirectSound (or the other options mentioned) is this will go directly to the hardware instead of using windows to convert the audio. This can increase performance but I think finding documentation and examples is going to be more difficult because this is a proprietary SDK. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

To just record audio in real time, any API will be fine. Note that WASAPI is the primary API (since Vista), and legacy APIs like WaveIn API, DirectSound are implemented on top of WASAPI as compatibility layers.

Regular APIs assume you are okay to certain processing latency/overhead, on the order of tens of milliseconds.

If you are going to be faster than this, and you need real time performance, such as to process data and return in back for playback as soon as possible, you need so called [exclusive mode streams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), where you can achieve latencies on the order of a few milliseconds, which is on par to professional audio development kits.

Windows SDK has a few audio recording samples in `\Samples\multimedia\audio` (C++)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a good idea to use a third party library for that. 
There's a multitude of options. The ones I know of are  [portaudio](http://www.portaudio.com/) and [STK](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/).

Answer (score 1):

I like the [Fmod API](http://www.fmod.org/fmod-ex/) which supports recording ([Sound recording with FMOD library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7000199/10396)) and realtime effects.